# How do i stop my array from resetting (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js, replit

I'm making a Discord.js bot and I have an array (it's declared outside of `client.on('message',msg =>{...` or anything else like that.  When I use bot commands to input some user IDs into the array print the array, it prints and works fine.

However, when I stop the program and restart it, the array resets, how can I stop this?
I'm using [repl.it](https://repl.it/) btw

Comment: Hard to say with the information you've given. What do you mean you're using repl.it? As a host?

Comment: That's typically expected for something like this. You would need to store your user list somewhere outside of your script (perhaps just a simple json file with the data) and pull that into the script when running.

Comment: You'll need to write to a file or have a db where it is stored.

Answer (score 1):

Array is indeed going to get reset once you restart the app. I suggest using a JSON file instead and storing contents inside of it.

e.g Create a file named array.json then include it at your app.js like this:
const array = require('./array.json')

You may check out this for guidance at JSON: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp